# Gradle project refresh failed (AS 0.5.5)

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have no idea what on earth is wrong, the project was working fine till I merged code from co-developer:

```
 Cause: org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeDependenciesExtractor.extractRepoFileDependencies(Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Collection;ZZ)Ljava/util/List;
            Gradle settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by upgrading to Android Studio beta version